# Como obtener dígito verificación de nit C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo entendido que el dígito de verificación de un nit se puede calcular. Me gustaría saber como se puede logar en codigo C# ya que estoy desarrollando en .net core 2.2.

Mil gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour], así sabrás cómo funciona el sitio y obtendrás tu primera medalla. ¿Puedes aclarar qué es un *nit*? O es un error de tipeo y te refieres a *bit*. Saludos

Comment: ¿qué es un nit? ¿en qué país?

Comment: Es el numero de identificación tributaria para colombia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que lo que necesitas esta en la wikipedia https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_de_Identificaci%C3%B3n_Tributaria

Allí hay un código ejemplo en c#

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, revisar [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool ValidarNIT(string digitoVerificacion, string numeroIdentificacion)
    {
        digitoVerificacion = digitoVerificacion.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "-1" : digitoVerificacion;
        var digitos = new byte[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroIdentificacion.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(numeroIdentificacion[i]))
                return false;
            digitos[i] = byte.Parse(numeroIdentificacion[i].ToString());
        }
        var v = 41 * digitos[0] +
                37 * digitos[1] +
                29 * digitos[2] +
                23 * digitos[3] +
                19 * digitos[4] +
                17 * digitos[5] +
                13 * digitos[6] +
                7 * digitos[7] +
                3 * digitos[8];
        v %= 11;
        if (v >= 2)
            v = 11 - v;
        return v == int.Parse(digitoVerificacion);
    }
```